# How to run an Azure Web App site in the Samsung TV browser

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, samsung-smart-tv

### DESCRIPTION

I've created a simple website using create-react-app and ASP.NET Core 2.1.

My website is live and works across desktop and mobile browsers, but not in the Internet app on a Samsung Smart TV.

---

### ERRORS

The message **Server Not Found** is displayed, even after I stripped the site to a bare bones html page so I don't think it's a JavaScript compatibility issue.

Loading the website in Chromium 23.0 produces this error:

> The server at www.xxx.azurewebsites.com* can't be found, because the
>   DNS lookup failed.

---

### MORE INFO

The SSL used is the one provided by Microsoft for *'azurewebsites.net'* so I would imagine it's pretty robust.

What could cause issues with connecting the server in this browser?

**Any ideas much appreciated!**

I have tried:

- Adding JavaScript polyfills
- Stripping the website to bare bones HTML
- Turning 'HTTPS Only' Off (in Azure Portal)
- Changing 'Minimum TLS Version' to 1.0 (in Azure Portal)
- Turning 'Incoming client certificates' Off (in Azure Portal)

Comment: Have you tried removing "www" from the URL?

Comment: Wow, it worked! It then loaded the site as "http:/....". Thank you so much! Why does this work?